# Differentiability of a piecewise (salt-pepper like) function

Tags: derivatives, piecewise-continuity

Today I ran into the following problem:

Let $f$ be a function such that
$$
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{4^n}, &x=\frac{1}{2^n}, \;\; n\in \{1,2,3,\ldots\} \\
0, &x\neq\frac{1}{2^n}
\end{cases} 
$$
Is the function $f$ differentiable at $0$?

So far, I have set the limit to show that the function is differentiable as:

$$
\lim_{h\to0} \frac{1}{h} f(h)
$$

I have a hunch that tells me that this limit is zero, as $f(h)$ seems to approach to zero faster than $h$. However, I have no idea how to prove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $f(h)$ is either $0$ or $h^{2}$. Hence $\frac {f(h)} h$ is either $0$ or $h$. Of course this tends to $0$ as $ h \to 0$ so $f'(0)=0$.